# How to make react-table header and checkbox fixed?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-table

I am using react-table with selectTable HOC.
I want to make checkbox and header both fixed.
I can make both individually fixed but when i tried to make fixed togather this is what happening.

Here is what i have tried.
https://codesandbox.io/s/jzr870m25

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to do this using position: sticky;

Here is example of it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/54z882qno4

Answer (score 0):

I prefer use [reactabular](https://github.com/reactabular/reactabular). So far, I think it's the best table library for React. But, it's a bit challenging.

You can see demo on [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/743v9967x0).

Comment: i can't change my table library.

Comment: Well, that's hard enough. I think you should post an issue on its repository. But, don't hesitate to give `reactabular` a try.

Comment: My development is already completed so i can't change table library. These are just enhancements. I have posted issue. just posted here to see if there is any other option available.

Comment: For a table component, i was working with react-table (pagination. manula pagination and filtering), but i am not able to get the code running, when i introduce filtering options. 

Looking around, i feel reactabular-table component is good, but i am unable to find any example for the same

My concern is, should i use table components(built-in) for tabular data in React, or build table from scratch. What should be the best way

Note--I am using latest version or react-table(with hooks)

Please help